Почему в слове "Здравствуйте" буква "в" не произносится?
Нужно объяснить иностранцу, почему в слове "здравствуйте" и подобных мы не произносим букву "в", по возможности привести ещё примеры.
Откуда эта буква берётся - понятно: этимология, однокоренные слова.
Но по какой причине мы её опускаем в процессе речи - вопрос.
Нашел утверждение: По правилам русского языка чтобы непроизносимая согласная была слышимой, необходимо изменить форму слова или подобрать однокоренное слово для проверки такие, что проверяемая согласная будет очевидной.
Звучит не до конца убедительно. Нужны ещё предположения, объяснения.
Прошу помочь, заранее спасибо!


ФОНЕТИЧЕСКАЯ СПРАВКА

Данная орфограмма относится к группе орфограмм, связанных с зубными звуками. Группу зубных согласных составляют звуки Т, Д, З, С, Ц, Л, Н с одинаковым местом образования.
Зубные согласные названы в соответствии с местом своего образования (при произношении зубных согласных кончик языка упирается в основании передних зубов), а различаются они по способу образования и по наличию или отсутствию голоса (для звонких и глухих зубных согласных).
Звук В – губно-зубный, поэтому он тоже относится к этой орфограмме.

ПРИЧИНА ОРФОГРАММЫ

Одинаковое место образование зубных согласных приводит к тому, что они оказывают значительное влияние друг на друга при произношении, что приводит к изменению отдельных звуков и является причиной различных орфограмм.
Причиной орфограммы «Непроизносимые согласные» является фонетическое чередование согласных звуков с нулём, а именно: при стечении трёх или более согласных, два из которых обычно зубные, некоторые звуки, например Т, Д, Л, В, не произносятся (что отражено в орфоэпическом словаре).

КАК ДЕЛАЕТСЯ ПРОВЕРКА НЕПРОИЗНОСИМОГО СОГЛАСНОГО

Для решения орфограммы необходимо ВОССТАНОВИТЬ количественный (а также качественный) звуковой состав корня, что осуществляется путём проверки с помощью родственных слов при изменении позиции звука, а именно: подбирается слово, в котором отсутствует стечение согласных.

Сочетание ВСТВ

Непроизносимый согласный В перед суффиксом СТВ (проверяется наличие В в корне перед суффиксом СТВ):
здравствовать – здравие – корень ЗДРАВ,
безмолвствовать – безмолвие, молва – корень МОЛВ,
девственный – дева – корень ДЕВ
Во всех примерах непроизносимый согласный В в корне перед суффиксом СТВ.
Но (нет В в проверяемых корнях):
участвовать – части – корень ЧАСТ,
путешествовать, шествовать предшествовать – шедший – корень ШЕ,
присутствовать – суть, по сути – корень СУТ.

КОНТРОЛЬ НЕПРОИЗНОСИМЫХ СОГЛАСНЫХ ПО СЛОВАРЮ (в единичных случаях)

Если стечение согласных происходит внутри корня, то написание слова контролируется по словарю. В этом случае происходит слияние исторического корня и суффикса, что можно установить с помощью этимологического словаря:
(1) ЧУВСТВО, предчувствие, чувственный – слияние корня ЧУВ и суффикса СТВ (ЧУВ – способность чувствовать; для сравнения: гневаться – гнев).

Искал медь, нашел золото. Большое спасибо!

Позволю себе внести немного ереси: https://rutube.ru/video/b906108e76f4a365cc3a190931cc08af/?t=28 ~28 секунда, "иль голос девственный, невинный", Лановой отчетливо произносит короткую В. У меня кстати тоже в слово девственный без в не звучит.   Тоже Смоктуновский, Ильин(не знаю кто это но читает хорошо) тут  - https://my.mail.ru/music/search/Я%20Вас%20люблю%2C%20хоть%20и%20бешусь..

Вот еще придумал: самоуправствуй, попробуйте произнести без В исходя из правила)

Правило? А какое правило?))  У меня же написано:  ...при стечении трёх или более согласных, два из которых обычно зубные, некоторые звуки, например Т, Д, Л, В, не произносятся (что отражено в ОРФОЭПИЧЕСКОМ словаре).  Из словаря на Грамоте: ДЕВСТВЕННЫЙ \ де[фст]венный, допуст. старш. де[фст’]венный и допуст. устарелое де[фс’т’]венный; девстве[н]ый и допуст. девстве[нн]ый.  Итак, произносится по словарю звук Ф.  Интересно, что в моем бумажном словаре Резниченко 2010 год написано: неправ. произн. Ф!  Не заю, что и думать, а вы что думаете? Кстати, рада вас видеть)

Другими словами, звуки могут не произноситься, но не обязаны, так что всем управляют орфоэпические словари, да еще на текущий момент.  Мы можем себе позволить их не произносить.  Разные могут быть причины, возможно, сказывается наличие похожего слово действенный https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=ДЕВСТВЕННЫЙ&mode=slovari&dicts[]=49

Тоже рад, что вы все еще трудитесь на благо русской грамматики. Возможно из-за наличия похожих слов, но девственный, девство( без Ф похоже на детство получится) хочется произносить с Ф(в), а не без, а вот здравствуй без Ф произносят все. Почему так, не знаю. То есть правило конечно придумать можно, но оно может и не работать всегда.

Кстати ещё подумал, в слове девственный слышится даже не Ф, а краткое В, она даже не редуцируется до глухого звука, а нарочито выпячивается.
